# Alamofire multitask Execution over after one func

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, alamofire, operation

use Alamofire multitask Execution  over  after one func.
my use gcd,`NSOperationQueue` all failure.
Please help me to solve the master.

The following pseudo code:

```
let imgDatas1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "aar")!, 0.1)
let strUrl1 = "http://www.baidu.com"


    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    //let queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue) {
        print("threed 1.1")
        Alamofire.upload(.POST, strUrl1, data: imgDatas1!).responseString(completionHandler: { (dd) in
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(3.0)
            print("threed1.3")
        })
        print("threed1.2")
    }
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue) {
        print("threed2.1")
        Alamofire.upload(.POST, strUrl1, data: imgDatas1!).responseString(completionHandler: { (dd) in
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2.0)
            print("threed2.3")
        })

        print("threed2.2")
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, queue) {
        print("voer")
    }





    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    let operation1 = NSBlockOperation {
        Alamofire.upload(.POST, strUrl1, data: imgDatas1!).responseString(completionHandler: { (dd) in
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2.0)
            print("xian 1.2")
        })
        print("xian 1.1")

    }
    let operation2 = NSBlockOperation {
        Alamofire.upload(.POST, strUrl1, data: imgDatas1!).responseString(completionHandler: { (dd) in
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(3.0)
            print("xian 2.2")
        })
        print("xian 2.1")
    }
    let operation3 = NSBlockOperation {
        print("xian 3")
    }
    operation2.addDependency(operation1)
    operation3.addDependency(operation2)

    operationQueue.addOperation(operation1)
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation2)
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with both of these approaches is that you're synchronizing the issuing of the requests, but not the actual response of the request. In your GCD example, you're exiting your `dispatch_group_async` as soon as the request is issued, although the response has not yet been received. Likewise in your operation queue example, you're completing your block operation as soon as the request is issued, but these operations aren't waiting for the requests to finish.

The simple, if inelegant approach is to just call one in the completion handler of the prior one. If you put them in separate functions, it avoids the unseemly nesting of completion handlers.

If you're looking for a more elegant solution, you solve this with operation queues by wrapping this in an asynchronous `NSOperation`/`Operation` subclass, and only trigger the `isFinished` KVO when the request is done. See *Asynchronous Versus Synchronous Operations* section of the [Operation Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operation), or the slightly more detailed (though dated) discussion in [Operation Queues: Concurrent Versus Non-concurrent Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW9) in the *Concurrency Programming Guide.*

Another elegant approach is to use promises, something like [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit). It strikes me as a fairly dramatic solution (introduce an entirely new asynchronous pattern), but it does solve this sort of issue well.